# Memory Leak From WebBrowser BSTR

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, webbrowser-control

I am experiencing a leak of some sort using webbrowser object; I am still surfing all over the place for answers -- I've seen some similar questions on this forum as well, but I cant see how to apply those findings in my case.

After a page loads the DocumentCompleted action fires and I parse the HTML on the page,

```
void PageScrollTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String pageSrc = webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml;

    // Check if we need to stop scrolling..
    if (m_iLastFramePageLength == pageSrc.Length)
    {
        m_iLastFramePageLength = 0;
        m_scrollTimer.Tick -= PageScrollTimerTick
        m_scrollTimer.Enabled = false;

        parsePage();
        nextPage();
    }
    else
    {
        m_iLastFramePageLength = pageSrc.Length;
        webBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height);
    }
}
```

The Leak:
[image: CLR Profile]

As I type this, I wonder why these functions? I have 6 different functions that do very similar tasks. I think these have problems because they are executed from a TIMER which probably uses a different thread. I'm I close? How can I resolve this. Perhaps Invoke() on the web browser control?

doParse():

```
List<String> doSomeExtractions()
{
    List<String> retVal = new List<String>();
    foreach (HtmlElement div in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
    {
        String szClassName = div.GetAttribute("classname");
        switch (szClassName)
        {
            case "someDivClass":
                {
                    if (div.InnerHtml.Contains("<b>"))
                    {
                        retVal.Add(div.InnerHtml);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    break;
                }
        }

    }

    return retVal;
}
```

moveNext():

```
// Store data, navigate to next page.
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += this.scrapeData;
webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
```

Comment: the invoke() made the allocation graphs more complicated, but that's about it.

Comment: What work does your parsePage and nextPage methods perform?

Comment: @AaronViviano Added some more details, I seem to only run into this issue when i mess with the Webcontrol's data outside of its normal event handler. All my other parse functions seem to be okay. In this instance function is called on a Forms.Timer callback.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I'm in the process of hunting down a similar problem ... so far I have identified that getting   `HtmlElement` objects from the `GetElementsByTagName` method is what leaks memory ... if I call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` on the `DomElement` property of `HtmlElement`, the leak stops. Want to understand this behavior so I can code properly in the future.

Comment: @TCC I did not resolve the issue, I wrote a "launcher" and focused my tasks which allowed me to restart the application often. I will note your response for the future, thank you!